# Add row in (div formate) html with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add row with remove button through **javascript** in **html** div formate.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com?)

Comment: I try to make a banner system like http://www.rightbanners.com/order-now.html I am weak in Java script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('<div>').append(
  $('<button>').text('remove').click(function(){$(this).parent().remove()})
).appendTo($(document.body))
```